# Create default value in form for Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation, model

I have a model:

```
namespace Modules\Acquisition\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AcqMBudgets extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $primaryKey = 'budget_id';
    
    protected $fillable = ['budget_code', 'budget_name', 'balance'];
    
    protected $attributes = [
        'balance' => 0,
    ];
}
```

On my controller:

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Acquisition\Http\Controllers;

use Modules\Acquisition\Entities\AcqMBudgets;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class BudgetController extends Controller
{
    //...//
    
    public function add()
    {
        return view('acquisition::budget.add');
    }

    //...//
}
```

and lastly on my view:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => '/acquisition/master/budget/create', 'method' => 'POST']) }}

<div class="row">
    {{ Form::label('budget_code', 'Code') }}
    {{ Form::text('budget_code', '') }}
</div>

<div class="row">
    {{ Form::label('budget_name', 'Name') }}
    {{ Form::text('budget_name', '') }}
</div>

<div class="row">
    {{ Form::label('balance', 'Balance') }}
    {{ Form::text('balance', '') }}
</div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

What I wanted is setting up the default value for `balance` to `0` when I displayed the form. I used this method based on Laravel 5.x documentation, but the result is always a blank text input? By the way, the table structure in database is as following:

```
table name: acq_m_budgets
----------
budget_id serial NOT NULL, -- The primary key
budget_code character varying(10) NOT NULL,
budget_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
balance numeric(16) DEFAULT 0,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [setting the default value](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#text) of the text input. You can do this like:

```
    {{ Form::text('balance', '0') }}
```

Or, if you have access to the $balance variable:

```
    {{ Form::text('balance', $balance) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @KurtFriars. Based on your answer, it means I define the default value in the views right? Not that there is anything wrong with that but, is it not possible to define all the rules and default values in model instead?

Comment: @Switch88 Yes, the second syntax allows for that. Say $balance was on Budget model, then you could use: {{ Form::text('balance', $budget->balance) }}, and it will default to whatever the model has for that value.

Comment: Where can I define the $budget variable? Does it means the $budget variable contain `AcqMBudgets` model as object?

Comment: Yes, it could be like ```$budget = AcqMBudgets::first();``` for example